# setting a value marked with JET_bitColumnAutoincrement with ESE

Tags: database, jet, extensible-storage-engine

I've created a column in ESE with the grbit set to JET_bitColumnAutoincrement - in normal usage this is what I want, for the value to be set to something unique by the database

however the way my database operates there are rare times when I need to set the value directly - I am 100% certain the ID I'm adding is not already in use - this is a rebuild type operation, it's not the normal case

is this possible?  is there a way to both be autoincrement while keeping the ability to set it on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the value directly. Esent would have to change the way autoincrement values are implemented to support that.